# How does AppCleaner know which files to delete and how can I find them using command line instead?

Tags: macos

I am trying to figure out how to clean uninstall pkg apps on macOS without relying on third party apps.

Comment: You would need to utilize `lsregister` to find the bundle ids, read the plists to get all the file locations, bindings, etc.  Start with `lsregister -dump > lsregister_dumpfile.txt` to get started

Comment: Thanks @Allan. Do you know why I am getting `zsh: command not found: lsregister`?

Comment: @Allan Never mind, read the manual... https://ss64.com/osx/lsregister.html

Comment: @Allan If you are up to it, I could use help figure this out... the output of `-dump` is overwhelming to say the least.

Comment: The part I am struggling with is "read the plists to get all the file locations, bindings".